# Don't understand db connrction

Tags: php, mysql

I downloaded this code but I don't understand the edit.

I would like to know what is `$host` and `$username`.

If I get a public server how do I change it

```
<?php
class Database
{

    private $host = "localhost";
    private $db_name = "test";
    private $username = "root";
    private $password = "";
    public $conn;

    public function dbConnection()
    {

        $this->conn = null;    
        try
        {
            $this->conn = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $this->host . ";dbname=" . $this->db_name, $this->username, $this->password);
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   
        }
        catch(PDOException $exception)
        {
            echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }

        return $this->conn;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: If you're using MySQL, go to PhpMyAdmin and create a new database and user. Then enter the same value here

Answer (score 2):

This is a PHP class that has some attributes and a method.  The code doesn't do anything by itself since the nothing has been instantiated.  I rewrote the code a little bit and added some comments.  Let me explain:

```
<?php
// Define a class. We will use this class later to create an object. The object will create a database connection.
class Database
{
    // Some attributes (variables for all objects created)
    public $conn;
    public $dsn;

    public function connect($host, $db_name, $username, $password)
    {
        // We are using PDO, so before we continue, have a brief look at this:
        // http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php

        // Create the DSN
        $this->dsn = 'mysql:dbname=' . $db_name . ';host=' . $host;
        // Try the following code, but catch any errors in the next code block
        try {
            $this->conn = new PDO($this->dsn, $username, $password);
            // Set connection attributes.  Learn more here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.setattribute.php
            $this->conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);   
        } catch(PDOException $e) {
            // echo the error if the try code block failed
            echo "Connection error: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
        // Return the connection.  You can assign a variable to the output of this method (function).
        return $this->conn;
    }
}

// Now instantiate the object to use the above code
$db = new Database();
$test = $db->connect('localhost', 'test', 'root', 'password');
```

Now, `$test` can be used to read, insert, update and delete data from the database.  And, the code is reusable.

```
$another = $db->connect('localhost', 'another', 'saferuser', 'password');
```

PDO Docs:

http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php (how to instantiate a PDO object)
http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php (entire docs)

Comment: you could also include link to official docs about [PHP PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.construct.php)

Comment: @tsg, yes, it's added.